# Calculating monthly returns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, finance, portfolio

This might be an insignificant question but unfortunately I'm unable to solve it. I have a portfolio of stocks of 50 companies. I have the dates and the closing prices on that particular day for each of the companies. Data for each company varies with respect to the date from which the stock is being traded.

I used this code for calculating the daily returns:

```
return=matrix(NA,nrow(companies),ncol(companies)-1)


for (j in 2:52){
  k=0
  for (i in 1:nrow(companies)){
    if (!is.na(companies[i,j]) & k==0) {
      base= companies[i,j]
      k=k+1
    }
    else {if ( k==1) {return[i,j-1] = ((companies[i,j]-base)/base)*100} 
          else {temp=0}
    }
  }
}
return[1:30,]
```

I now want to calculate the monthly returns for the same portfolio of companies. The formula I am using to calculate this is:

```
Return = [(Price on Last day of month) - (Price on other day)]*100/(Price on last day of month)
```

I want to repeat this process for 12 months in a year and for a period of 12 years (since that is the duration of data I have). I am planning to write a for loop to do this calculation. Could someone please help me out with this. Unfortunately, I cannot use the quantmod package since the stock prices are from the Indian Stock Exchange, from which quantmod can't read the prices.

Comment: how does your data date look like? 2001-09-11 ?

Comment: If I can do it with `quantomod`, my first reflex would be to format my data to use this good package.

Comment: @agstudy is right: it'll be lots simpler to write a line or two of code which reads IndianStock format and writes it out to a format `quantmod` recognizes.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft is right too.  It shouldn't be very difficult to get the data into R.  But, if it is, you can most likely use yahoo as the data source.  Try, for example, `getSymbols(c("BPCL.NS", "HPCL.BO"), src="yahoo")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should definitly use `quantmod`, and you can. The `quantmod` methods `monthlyReturn, dailyReturn, ..., allReturns` require an `xts` time series as input. So if you have daily data (e.g. close price) and the corresponding dates you can construct your time series and pass that to the desired `quantmod` method.

Example:

```
library(package="quantmod")

prices <- c(7655.88, 7612.39, 7612.39, 7778.78, 7756.44, 7776.37)
dates <- as.Date(c("2012-12-26", "2012-12-27", "2012-12-30", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03"))
ts <- xts(prices, dates)

dailyReturn(ts)
monthlyReturn(ts) # this will return bogus data because we don't have one month of data in this example
```

Comment: Actually, they don't require an `xts` object

Comment: I actually have data for these companies for the past 12 years (i.e since 2000). But the data available for most of these companies is only from about 2004 or so in yahoo Finance, thus making it difficult for me to use the package. It is possible for me to use the data I have, in a csv file, in quantmod?

Comment: 06-Jan-00 1355.85 

That is the format of my data. I have 52 columns and about 3300 rows of data.

Comment: Also, another problem I am facing with this package is the formulae being used for calculation of returns. Since the methods I am using to calculate returns are different from what the quantmod package is employing, I want to write a code to calculate the returns.