# R: Calculate monthly returns by group based on daily prices

Tags: r, return, time-series, quantmod, stock

I have a large dataframe `crsp` that contains several columns of daily stock data. Relevant for this question are the following columns (small extract to give you an idea):

```
PERMNO   date         monthyear  PRC       RET
10001    1990-01-02   199001     10.1250   0.0000
10001    1990-01-03   199001     10.0000  -0.0123
...
10001    1990-02-01   199002     10.0000   0.0000
10001    1990-02-02   199002     10.0625   0.0062
...
10002    1990-01-02   199001      6.1250   0.0000
10002    1990-01-03   199001      6.2000   0.0122
...
10002    1990-02-01   199002      6.2500   0.0000
10002    1990-02-02   199002      6.5000   0.0400
...
```

`"PERMNO"` is the stock ID, `"date"` the actual date, `"monthyear"` indicates the month, `"PRC"` is the price and `"RET"` the daily return.

I am trying to add a new column `"MonthlyReturn"` which shows the monthly return for each stock. The value should therefore be calculated for each month of each stock (grouped by PERMNO).

As far as my knowledge goes, there could be two possibilities to solve this:

1. Calculate the monthly return through dividing the last price of each month of each stock through the first price of the month (careful: due to weekends the first trading day of the month is not necessarily the actual 1st day of the month)
2. Convert the existing daily returns to monthly returns

Either way, I am aiming for the following output:

```
PERMNO   date         monthyear  PRC       RET      MonthlyReturn
10001    1990-01-02   199001     10.1250   0.0000   0.1000
10001    1990-01-03   199001     10.0000  -0.0123   0.1000
...
10001    1990-02-01   199002     10.0000   0.0000   0.0987
10001    1990-02-02   199002     10.0625   0.0062   0.0987
...
10002    1990-01-02   199001      6.1250   0.0000  -0.0034
10002    1990-01-03   199001      6.2000   0.0122  -0.0034
...
10002    1990-02-01   199002      6.2500   0.0000   0.2340
10002    1990-02-02   199002      6.5000   0.0400   0.2340
...
```

Through research I came upon the monthlyReturn-function from quantmod, could this be useful?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I just started learning R. Also feel free to add anything that could help me improve this question's suitability for SO.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Take a look at this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599538/calculate-the-monthly-returns-with-data-frames-in-r

Comment: @cyrilb38: I've seen these threads. Unfortunately there is a slight difference for my case since I have to apply this approach to daily data while optimally using monthlyReturn() AND grouping it by PERMNO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tidyverse, you can calculate your monthly return this way :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- left_join(df, df %>%
  arrange(PERMNO, date) %>% # order the data  by stock id and date
  filter(!wday(as.Date(date)) %in% c(1,7)) %>% # filter week end
  group_by(PERMNO, monthyear) %>% 
  mutate(MonthlyReturn = last(PRC) / first(PRC) - 1) %>% # calculate the monthly return per stock id and month
  select(PERMNO, monthyear, MonthlyReturn)) # Keep only these 3 columns
```

Hope this helps.